# ArcGIS REST Api Blob Format

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

Using the arcgis REST api (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/) using the addFeatures link http://example.com//arcgis/rest/services/name/name/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures how do you add a blob. We've tried the following,

```
[
{
   "geometry" : {"x" : -118.15, "y" : 33.80},          "attributes" : {
     "name" : "Joe Smith",
     "title" : "Test",
     "descr": "324DFIOWNF83294"
   }
 }
]
```

does not work (error being Unable to complete operation,   "Setting of value for descr failed.") however

```
[
{
   "geometry" : {"x" : -118.15, "y" : 33.80},          "attributes" : {
     "name" : "Joe Smith",
     "title" : "Test",
     "descr": null
   }
 }
]
```

**edit Base64**:

I also tried the following base64 version as Vince suggested

```
VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXh0IGVuY29kZWQgaW4gYmFzZTY0Lg==
```

being

```
This is text encoded in base64.
```

with the following,

```
[
{
   "geometry" : {"x" : -118.15, "y" : 33.80},          "attributes" : {
     "name" : "Joe Smith",
     "title" : "Test",
     "descr": "VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXh0IGVuY29kZWQgaW4gYmFzZTY0Lg=="
   }
 }
]
```

doesn't work.

What encoding does ArcGIS's REST service expect the blob to be in.

The field types are

```
name - esriFieldTypeString

title - esriFieldTypeString

descr - esriFieldTypeBlob
```

Specifically descr is,

```
descr ( type: esriFieldTypeBlob , alias: desc , editable: true , nullable: true )
```

ArcGIS Server version is 10.3.1

Comment: You should probably try base64.

Comment: @vince Tried with the following base 64 VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXh0IGVuY29kZWQgaW4gYmFzZTY0Lg== . Is there some type of content type I have to somehow set? See the edit above for the full submission

Comment: You say it "does work", does this mean base64 works?

Comment: You should also query an existing feature, and see how it is returned.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall doesn't work, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The ArcGIS Rest API does not support BLOBs for the JSON feature object. From  the documentation:

> The values are the field values, and they can be any of the standard
>   JSON types: string, number, and boolean.
>   [ArcGIS REST API - Feature Object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Feature_object/02r3000000n8000000/)

Is there a reason you can't use [Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Attachment_Feature_Service/02r3000000r2000000/) in your project?

Comment: Because the data is things we'd want to filter or sort on, for example a text field greater than 255 characters (the limit of the actual text field for Arcgis). For example maybe there is a comment field on a point and to have more than 255 characters you'd have to use a blob but you'd still may want to search against it (which an attachment makes awkward). 

I did see the note on JSON types, but I'm confused why a blob wouldn't just be a string of some sort (base 64, etc).

Answer (score 0):

What we ended up doing is modifying the text length to 1500 instead of 255, this was done through the server database I believe. It was confirmed that for a long time there was a text limit of 255 and I swore I read that somewhere (however can't seem to find it).

I was unable to get the BLOB format working at all, neither through REST API or Javascript. My recommendation is to just increase the text length and use a esriFieldTypeString field. The other option is to use attachments which works for somethings as long as you don't have to search for it.

Summary: Extend the esriFieldTypeString field from a default of 255 to whatever you need. It seems in the past there was a limit of 255 but that is no longer the case it's just the default.